# Is there a way of triggering the back button through a button click in a webpage?

Tags: android, web-applications

I want to provide a button in a webpage. after clicking it user has to be redirected to app ,app from which he has opened the webpage.My thought of doing it is triggering android back button after user clicks button in webpage.Is this a way even possible or is there any other way of doing it.

Comment: That is default behavior of the android right?

Comment: yes, you need to use JavaScript inteface, or capture link that button suppose to open

Comment: I don't want user to press android back button.My use case is I will be asking user to upload image after redirecting to my webpage.After uploading image and upon clicking ok I have to redirect him directly to the app.

Comment: @AntonisRadz can you explain me in brief how can i do that with javascript interface.I don't want to use capturing link.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#BindingJavaScript

Answer (score 1):

This creates an interface called Android for JavaScript running in the WebView. At this point, your web application has access to the WebAppInterface class. For example, here's some HTML and JavaScript that creates a toast message using the new interface when the user clicks a button:

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
```

you can include the following class in your Android app:

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `JavascriptInterface` for communication between `WebView` and app.

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#BindingJavaScript)